# How to subtract two label values in ARM64 assembly using clang's as(1)?

Tags: macos, assembly, arm64

I found an ARM64/MacOS "Hello, World" program that looks like this:

```
.global _main
.align 2 

_main: mov X0, #1
       adr X1, helloworld
       mov X2, #13
       mov X16, #4
       svc 0

       mov X0, #0 
       mov X16, #1
       svc 0

helloworld:      .ascii  "Hello World!\n"
```

What I'd like to do is eliminate the hard-coded string-length (`mov X2, #13`). But I can't figure out how to get `as` to subtract two label values for use in an expression.

I tried adding `helloend:` after the string and doing

```
mov X2, #helloend - helloworld
```

Which got me this message:

```
hello.s:6:9: error: unknown AArch64 fixup kind!
    mov X2, #helloend - helloworld
```

I also tried doing a runtime subtraction, but trying to use `=label` as a parameter to the `sub` instruction gave me the same "error: unknown AArch64 fixup kind!" message.

I'm using the `as` that's part of clang 14.0.3.

What's the solution?

Comment: What happened when you tried to subtract? That should work, and it does here. E.g. put a `helloworld_end:` after the string and then do `mov X2, #helloworld_end - helloworld`. Alternatively you can do `.equ helloworld_len, . - helloworld` after the string and then use `mov X2, #helloworld_len`.

Comment: @Jester: edited to add what I tried and the error I received.

Comment: What is your assembler version? I have 2.25.1.

Comment: @Jester I'm on macOS, so I'm using clang as. Specifically, version 14.0.3.

Comment: You could use GNU `as` anyway :) Did you try the `.equ` version? Does that give the same error? If all else fails, your runtime workaround should be something like `adr x2, helloend; sub x2, x2, x1`

Comment: The .equ gave the same error - on the `mov x2, #len` line. But the subtraction with registers worked, so I guess that'll do for now.

Comment: The `.equ` approach works here.  Can you post the full code you tried?  There might be some other problem with it.

Comment: I think the issue is that with `mov x2, #(end - begin)`, the assembler tries to emit fixups to have the linker do the subtraction and encode the result into the instruction.   This isn't supported.  But `.equ len, end-begin` forces the subtraction to be done within the assembler, and then it can encode the immediate directly.

Comment: @NateEldredge must have done something weird the first time; now it worked. If one of you turns that into an answer I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new symbol with the length, then `mov` it into a register.

```
len = helloend - helloworld
mov x2, #len
```

Or `.equ len, helloend - helloworld` works too.  You can shorten it a bit by defining it right after the string:

```
helloworld:      .ascii  "Hello World!\n"
len = . - helloworld
```

I think the issue is that with `mov x2, #(end - begin)`, the assembler tries to emit fixups to have the linker do the subtraction and encode the result into the instruction. This isn't supported. But `len = end - begin` forces the subtraction to be done within the assembler, and then it can encode the immediate directly.